# Смена цвета фиксированной шапки

Tags: header, color, background, fixed

Собственно в чем вопрос! Интересует реализация смены цвета бэкграунда фиксированного хедера при скролле! Находясь в определенной секции лендинга(home/about/work/ и т.д.). Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: вешаете событие онскролл, и в точке, в которой нужно меняете собственно цвет

Comment: Так, а теперь подробнее! Нельзя ли показать пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упрощенный способ, если у вас не будет дополнительных классов у шапки

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var currentclass
    $('section').each(function(){
       if($(this).offset().top<$(window).scrollTop()){
          currentclass =$(this).attr('id')
       }
       
    })
    $('header').attr('class',currentclass)
})
```

```css
header{
    position:fixed;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
}
section{
    height:700px;
}
.home{
    background:red;
}
.about{
    background:blue;
}
.contacts{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<section id=home></section>
<section id=about></section>
<section id=contacts></section>
```

Comment: Отлично! То что нужно, коротко и ясно! Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rrtmmyj9/
Пример смены бг по позиции экрана и нужно вам блока

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 $('.two').offset().top;
 if ($('.two').offset().top >= pageYOffset) {
  $('.two').css('background',"blue");
 }
})
```